# json not loading in iphone device while using sencha touch and phonegap

Tags: json, cordova, extjs

I'm trying to load a json into my view. Im using phonegap with sencha touch and when I load the app to my phone the json does not load at all.. It works fine in the browser and in the simulator.
I would really appreciate some help from the experts

Here is the main code that im trying:

the store:

App.stores.freebees = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Freebee',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'fixtures/freebees',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

the list view:

App.views.FreebeesList = Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
    id: 'indexlist',
    layout: 'fit',
    store: App.stores.freebees,
    itemTpl: '{companyName}, {title}, {address}',

```
listeners: {
    'itemtap': function(list, index, item, obj) {
        Ext.dispatch({
            controller: 'Freebee',
            action: 'showDetails',
            id: list.getRecord(item).data.id,
            lat: list.getRecord(item).data.lat,
            longitude: list.getRecord(item).data.longitude,
            companyName: list.getRecord(item).data.companyName,
            address: list.getRecord(item).data.address,

        });
    }
},
initComponent: function() {
    App.views.FreebeesList.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

});
Ext.reg('App.views.FreebeesList', App.views.FreebeesList);

the json:

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Freebee 1",
        "companyName": "Företaget AB 1",
        "address": "Ekuddsvägen 1 Nacka 131 38 Sweden",
        "lat": 59.3058,
        "longitude": 18.1463
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Freebee 2",
        "companyName": "Företaget AB 2",
        "address": "Ekuddsvägen 2 Nacka 131 38 Sweden",
        "lat": 59.305,
        "longitude": 18.1478
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

From my limited experiece with ST so far, you cant load a file which is on the device like that. You may have to load the json file using a script tag and pass it in as data.

```
data = [ { "id": 1, "title": "Freebee 1", "companyName": "Företaget AB 1", "address": "Ekuddsvägen 1 Nacka 131 38 Sweden", "lat": 59.3058, "longitude": 18.1463 }, { "id": 2, "title": "Freebee 2", "companyName": "Företaget AB 2", "address": "Ekuddsvägen 2 Nacka 131 38 Sweden", "lat": 59.305, "longitude": 18.1478 } ];
```

then load it into your store like so:

```
App.stores.freebees = new Ext.data.Store({ model: 'Freebee', root:data, autoLoad: true, proxy: { type: 'ajax', url: 'fixtures/freebees', reader: { type: 'json' } } });
```

(added root:data)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i get this error:


Uncaught Ext.data.JsonReader.getResponseData: Unable to parse JSON 
returned by Server.

I have a validated json from jsonlint
It is very strange because everything works fine in the simulator and on the browser, but nothing works on the actual iphone.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.. Please see my question and answer here:

[Sencha parses JSON in iphone simulator, but not on iPhone - phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176899/sencha-parses-json-in-iphone-simulator-but-not-on-iphone-phonegap/8177299#8177299)