# Sencha parses JSON in iphone simulator, but not on iPhone - phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch

I have the following code in a Sencha Touch App that parses a JSON response from the server.The app is wrapped around Phonegap and being deployed as a native app on the iPhone. This code works fine on the iPhone Simulator but not on the iPhone itself.

There's a similar question already roaming around SO, unanswered: [json not loading in iphone device while using sencha touch and phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118415/json-not-loading-in-iphone-device-while-using-sencha-touch-and-phonegap)

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: makeurl,    //'http://hostname/index.php?id=1234&action=STARTLIST&cmd=0',
    scope : this,
    success: function(response){
        GoRemote.views.devicelist.setLoading(false);
        GoRemote.serverstatus="Ok";
        Ext.getCmp('serverstatuspanel').update('Server Status : Okay');
        this.listData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        console.log(response);
        if (this.listData.listresponse) {
            GoRemote.stores.RoomDeviceListStore.loadData(this.listData.listresponse.listdata, false);
            GoRemote.views.toolbar.setTitle(this.listData.listresponse.listinfo.listname);
              if(this.listData.listresponse.listinfo.container){
                  Ext.getCmp('btnBack').setVisible(true);
              }
              else{
                  Ext.getCmp('btnBack').setVisible(false);
              }
        }  
        else if(this.listData.listcontrol){
            if(this.listData.listcontrol.controlinfo.name=="NIAVDevice"){
                Ext.getCmp('navigation').setActiveItem(0);
            }
        }  
    },
    failure:function(response){
        GoRemote.serverstatus="Unable to reach director";
        Ext.getCmp('serverstatuspanel').update('Server Status : Unable to reach director');
        GoRemote.views.devicelist.setLoading(false);
    }
  //  timeout:20000
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, we managed to fix the error... The server was a custom built and in the Response Headers was responding with HTTP/1.0 where we needed to have HTTP/1.1

Little thing, big impact.

Thanks!